# WindowsPhone App not working right if installed via Store, but works as it should in the emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have made an (demo) app that does have a link (if you click on the bottom, there is a banner) in it for the full version. I tested it in the emulator and deployed on my Lumia 920 too and all worked perfectly. Later I published the app in the Store and tested the app again.

If I click on the same banner in the app installed from the Store, nothing happens.

Anyone knows where's the problem and how can I resolve it ?

Here is the link of the app:

http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=3186dc8f-19a5-4370-a963-2da34d2d2831

EDIT: here is the code of the banner:

```
<Image Source="/Assets/Demo/demo-store-icon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="55" Height="65" Margin="0,0,0,5" Tap="Store"/>

        private void Store(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.Source = new Uri("http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=2a6a3a96-04c3-410d-a01e-480742143feb");
    }
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to guess the issue without the code of the banner ;)

Comment: Here it is, I edited the post, take a look.

Comment: @fillobotto but why does it work if deployed directly on phone than ?

Comment: Please forget my previuos comment. Have a look to Bahti's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what is wrong with your code, but there is a marketplace detail task which you can insert to your code easily. Here is a sample code and description:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(CurrentApp.LinkUri);
```